# Failed to connect to Hyperledger peer when TLS is enabled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc, hyperledger-fabric-ca

When I try to connect to Hyperledgerpeer with TLS enabled I get the following error. If I disable TLS it works well.

```
{ Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
at checkState (/Users/pro/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:720:16) connectFailed: true }
```

Did anyone come across this? I have set up TLS Cert and key on docker env variables.

Comment: How are you connecting to the peers?

Comment: THrough connection profile. Followed this (https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html)